# Should a hosted service be used in an ASP.NET Core Web API project when that service has to run before requests are made?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I've added a hosted service to my ASP.NET Core Web API project:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ScheduledProcessingService>();
```

However, `Main()` and `Startup` don't get hit until a request comes in. That means my hosted service doesn't start until then. When running locally, when I start the app, I have to make a call to the API controller (which I'd like not to have to do) in order for the hosted service to run.

If my hosted service *has* to process, regardless of whether a web request comes in, is it wrong to put that service in a Web API project? Should I create a separate project for it?

I could change some IIS settings, like in [this post](https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/), but I want to make sure I'm doing what's right.

Comment: hosted service lives along with the app. That's enough for many use cases. But if you want it to always run, the app must be so as well. That's why there are some ways to keep the app running such as by periodically pinging it using some simple request.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: @KingKing Ok, so the answer to my question is really something has to ping the app, otherwise the hosted service won't run. That's what I needed to know.

Comment: @JoeH I have not. I'll check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone provides more clarity, I think this is the answer:

It's hosted in IIS so it's just how it works. To overcome this, I think we'd have to set up some automatic ping, hangfire.io, or simply putting it in its own project that is just a service.

Another option would be to change these settings on the app pool:

- .NET CLR version: v4.0 (instead of no managed code)
- Start mode: always running
- Idle time-out: 0

Another suggestion:
We use the app initialization feature in IIS to start and keep the services running.